# Style bootstrap table buttons - btn-primary dropdown-toggle

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, bootstrap-table

How can I style bootstrap table buttons fully, currently the buttons remain blue and hovering over my table buttons only makes half of the button the colour I want, I would like the button black (#282828) and then just slightly lighter when hovered over or active.

JSFiddle at bottom of question

[image: Hovering over the right button in the picture]

My table is generated by javascript

```
 function bootstrapTableStateHandler(origin, msg, type) {
    console[type]("[bootstrapTable." + origin + "]", msg)
}
 var $table = $('#results');
         $table.bootstrapTable({
              url: 'getresults.php',
              search: true,
              buttonsClass: 'primary',
              showFooter: false,
              minimumCountColumns: 2,
              columns: [{
                  field: 'results',
                  title: 'results',
                  sortable: true,
              }, ....So on and so forth
```

And the drop down turned on by this in the table

```
<table id="results" data-show-columns="true" data-show-toggle="true"></table>
```

I have tried to style everything using the CSS below and the button remains blue, when I hover over it only half the button turns black - the outline does turn black though - sorry for so much CSS

```
.btn-primary { 
  color: #ffffff !important; 
  background-color: #282828 !important; 
  border-color: #292730; 
} 

.btn-primary:hover, 
.btn-primary:focus, 
.btn-primary:active, 
.btn-primary.active, 
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary { 
  color: #ffffff; 
  background-color: #282828 !important; 
  border-color: #282828 !important; 
} 

.btn-primary:active, 
.btn-primary.active, 
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary { 
  background-image: none; 
} 

.btn-primary.disabled, 
.btn-primary[disabled], 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary, 
.btn-primary.disabled:hover, 
.btn-primary[disabled]:hover, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover, 
.btn-primary.disabled:focus, 
.btn-primary[disabled]:focus, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:focus, 
.btn-primary.disabled:active, 
.btn-primary[disabled]:active, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:active, 
.btn-primary.disabled.active, 
.btn-primary[disabled].active, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.active { 
  background-color: #1F1B1B; 
  border-color: #282828 !important; 
} 

.btn-primary .badge { 
  color: #1F1B1B; 
  background-color: #282828 !important; 
}
.dropdown-toggle { 
  color: #ffffff; 
  background-color: #282828 !important; 
  border-color: #292730; 
} 

.dropdown-toggle:hover, 
.dropdown-toggle:focus, 
.dropdown-toggle:active, 
.dropdown-toggle.active, 
.open .dropdown-toggle.dropdown-toggle { 
  color: #ffffff; 
  background-color: #282828 !important; 
  border-color: #282828 !important; 
} 

.dropdown-toggle:active, 
.dropdown-toggle.active, 
.open .dropdown-toggle.dropdown-toggle { 
  background-image: none; 
} 

.dropdown-toggle.disabled, 
.dropdown-toggle[disabled], 
fieldset[disabled] .dropdown-toggle, 
.dropdown-toggle.disabled:hover, 
.dropdown-toggle[disabled]:hover, 
fieldset[disabled] .dropdown-toggle:hover, 
.dropdown-toggle.disabled:focus, 
.dropdown-toggle[disabled]:focus, 
fieldset[disabled] .dropdown-toggle:focus, 
.dropdown-toggle.disabled:active, 
.dropdown-toggle[disabled]:active, 
fieldset[disabled] .dropdown-toggle:active, 
.dropdown-toggle.disabled.active, 
.dropdown-toggle[disabled].active, 
fieldset[disabled] .dropdown-toggle.active { 
  background-color: #282828 !important; 
  border-color: #282828 !important; 
} 

.dropdown-toggle .badge { 
  color: #1F1B1B; 
  background-color: #282828 !important; 
}
```

What do I need to style to force the table buttons to be black (#282828)
Looking at the output of the page, the button when inspected is called btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle

Thank you

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4unyu5tz/)

Comment: Can you provide the html of the button(s) only and the css? Preferably in a working JS-Fiddle. I think the javascript you used to generate the html might not be relevant to the question if you provide the html.

Comment: Added JSFiddle of my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `background` instead of `background-color` you should be able to override the settings. This is because these bootstrap uses linear-gradients which are a background-image and will be on top. So you need to override this property in order for your color to be seen. You could also use `background-image: none` and `background-color: #282828`, but just using `background: #282828` gets the job done and is less to manage.

https://jsfiddle.net/bonez0607/0qkubms6/

```
.btn-primary { 
  color: #ffffff !important; 
  background: #282828; 
  border-color: #292730; 
} 

.btn-primary:hover, 
.btn-primary:focus, 
.btn-primary:active, 
.btn-primary.active, 
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary { 
  color: #ffffff; 
  background: #484848; 
  border-color: #282828 !important; 
} 

.btn-primary:active, 
.btn-primary.active, 
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary { 
  background-image: none; 
} 

.btn-primary.disabled, 
.btn-primary[disabled], 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary, 
.btn-primary.disabled:hover, 
.btn-primary[disabled]:hover, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover, 
.btn-primary.disabled:focus, 
.btn-primary[disabled]:focus, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:focus, 
.btn-primary.disabled:active, 
.btn-primary[disabled]:active, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:active, 
.btn-primary.disabled.active, 
.btn-primary[disabled].active, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.active { 
  background-color: #1F1B1B; 
  border-color: #282828; 
} 

.btn-primary .badge { 
  color: #1F1B1B; 
  background-color: #282828 !important; 
}
.dropdown-toggle { 
  color: #ffffff; 
  background: #282828; 
  border-color: #292730; 
} 

.dropdown-toggle:hover, 
.dropdown-toggle:focus, 
.dropdown-toggle:active, 
.dropdown-toggle.active, 
.open .dropdown-toggle.dropdown-toggle { 
  color: #ffffff; 
  background: #484848; 
  border-color: #282828 !important; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to replicate the issue. I came up with this code: https://jsfiddle.net/gemkzwva/. It explains what happens in the code.

```
<button></button>
<button id="fixed"></button>

button{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, blue);/*bootstrap-theme behaviour*/
}
button:hover{
  background-position: 0 25px;/*bootstrap-theme behaviour*/
}
#fixed:hover{
  background-position: 0; /*override background-position */
  background-image: none; /*remove the bootstrap-theme image/linear-gradient*/
  background-color: green;
}
```

The behaviour of the `background-image` and `background-position` is triggered by the .btn-primary class in your bootstrap-theme.min.css file. So you could:

- remove that theme.
- make appropriate overrides.
- remove the btn-primary class and create a custom one in your own code.